# Specifically target older version of single .NET Standard API/namespace (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I am in the process of upgrading .NET Core to 2.1 in my app. With the latest SDK (2.1.300), .NET Standard has two versions of Entity Framework Core. So, when I right click the line below and click "Go To Definition" I get the options in the below screenshot.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

[image: Go To Definition]

Notice both 2.1.0.0 and 2.0.3.0 of Entity Framework Core. I am assuming that, by default, I am targeting the highest version available (2.1.0.0). I would like to specifically target 2.0.3.0 since I believe my class library's EF data provider [currently has an incompatibility](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/514) with 2.1.0.0. But, I would like to continue using the latest version of the SDK. Is there a way to achieve this by somehow specifying the version number of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to use?

I have already worked through the [2.x to 2.1 migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1) if that matters. Here are the relevant parts of my class library's .csproj for reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up some things there:

- The .NET Core SDK mostly determines the tooling that is available to you. Unless you have a good reason, you should always run the latest SDK. So you should use the current version `2.1.300` of the SDK. The SDK version has no direct impact on what *runtime* you will be using.
- If you want to run an ASP.NET Core application on version 2.1 on .NET Core, then you will have to use the `netcoreapp2.1` target framework.
- Obviously, you will have to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages with version 2.1.
- If you want to use Entity Framework Core with version 2.0.x, then you need to explicitly reference that. Note that you *cannot* use the shared framework reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in that case.

So a project that uses ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Core 2.1, using Entity Framework 2.0 with the Pomelo MySQL provider could look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If you are not trying to do this within an ASP.NET Core web project but in a library project instead, then you are targetting `netstandard2.0`. In that case, you just need to import the proper packages directly:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Note that Entity Framework Core is **not** included in the .NET Standard, it is merely targetting it which means that it builds on top of the standard; just like your library project.

If you want to consume your library project from within an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application, then the restriction mentioned above will still apply: You cannot use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework reference, since that will cause version conflicts.